# Tooltips are mispositioned on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-tools

I cannot for the life of me figure out why the jQuery Tools Tooltips are showing up in the wrong place. Hover over the one of the three gray boxes on [this](http://walkthehall.com/pages/overview) page (e.g. "screen & voice recording"), and the tips should show up on top of the box centered.

Comment: There is no need to use a URL shortener. Are you trying to clear the `referrer`?

Comment: @alex, no just not wanting the URL to get indexed.

Answer (score 2):

There is an `offset` property that can be uses to nudge the tooltip to correct position: http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html#positioning. Just scroll up a bit to the table and there it explains the `offset` property. Just be sure you check the site on multiple browsers, so that you can be sure the `offset` doesn't need to change.

It looks to me that the offset should be about `[0, -150]`. Try this:

```
$(".tooltip").tooltip({
    track: true,
    delay: 0,
    showURL: false,
    showBody: " - ",
    fade: 250,
    offset : [0, -150]
});
```

Comment: Thanks SimpleCoder. I updated it with the offset, and it's different on Windows and Mac. Both FF/Safari Mac show it about 150px further to the right, while IE6/7/8/FF/Chrome Windows all show it centered now. It seems like I might need to fix the root problem, because they were once originally aligned but somehow over the course of the project got out of whack. Any ideas?

Comment: You will most likely need to test the site on different browsers, so you can fine-tune the offset for each of them. I'm not sure why the offset is actually needed, but as long as the offset works, I don't see a problem with using it.

Answer (score 0):

On the element style in the source code (checked with [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com)) I found this:

*for #recording-tip*

```
element.style 
{
display:none;
    left:371.5px;
opacity:0;
position:absolute;
top:391.2px;
}
```

This left property is causing it to display in the "wrong" place. I use the same plugin for my tooltips, remove this left property in the style and you should be set :)

**Edit:** After some more playing around, I found out that this is added by the jQuery itself, but this isn't present in the version I am using, are you using some custom animation or effects?